# Compressed row storage: What happens if last row is all zeros?

Tags: sparse-matrices

I am studying [compressed row storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_row_Storage_.28CRS_or_CSR.29) (CRS format) for storing an sparse matrix. I can't tell how this works if the matrix has a row with all entries zero, and in particular, what happens with the pointer `row_ptr`. Could you describe the `val`, `col_ind` and `row_ptr` vectors for the following matrix?

\begin{bmatrix}
 2 &  0 & 0\\ 
 0 &  0 & 1\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Looking for this, somebody suggested me "if row $i$ contains entirely zeros, you store in `row-ptr`$(i)$ the same as in `row-ptr`$(i+1)$" but what happens when the entries of last row are all 0s?

Comment: This sounds like a programming question. Perhaps take a look at the source code.

Comment: More generally, I think that low level questions about file formats are off topic. (Higher level questions could be appropriate.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is off-topic.  It looks like it might be a question about a particular data structure for storing sparse matrices, which would presumably be on-topic (?).  But I'm not sure, as I'm not familiar with compressed row storage, and I don't know if it's specific to a particular software package or programming framework.